# @Media print styles are not applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvdy1q 
I want to print specific `div`.

```
<div id="forPrint" (click)="onPrint('23')">
  <div id="printable">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
onPrint(url) {
  this.mode = 'print';
  const mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

  mywindow.document.write(`<html><head><title>${document.title}</title>`);
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write(`<h1> www.${url}</h1>`);
  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('forPrint').innerHTML);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();

  return true;
}
```

Stlyles:

```
@media print {
  html,
  body {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100%!important;
    h1 {
      color: #1c7430;
    }
  }
  #printable {
    display: flex!important;
    justify-content: center!important;
    align-items: center!important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 700px!important;
  }
  .box {
    width: 100px!important;
    height: 100px!important;
    background: green!important;
  }
}
```

But after print dialog is opened, the box is not shown. So no styles are applied such as `h1`, `.box`. What is the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to close  `html, body{..}` then `h1{}`

Comment: Are you using a preprocessor such as SCSS or LESS? If not, your CSS syntax is incorrect. Your `h1` styles are nested within the `html, body` styles.

Comment: @Turnip yes I am using SCSS preprocessor.

Comment: Your javascript is creating a new document but you aren't loading your CSS in this document.

Comment: @Turnip please check stackblitz. I also add manually https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvdy1q

Comment: As Turnip already said: your `@media print` applies only to the main page, not to the new window that you create temporarily. And why even create a new window for printing, because using `@media print` can work fine (and with less hassle building a whole new window) by printing the main page and simply making it hide the elements that you don't want to print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to somehow inject your CSS into the new page.

Here I create a `style` tag and add the CSS directly. You could alternatively link to a stylesheet:

```
function onPrint(url) {
  this.mode = 'print';
  const mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

  const styles = `html,
      body {
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100%!important;
      }
      h1 {
          color: #1c7430;
      }
      #printable {
        display: flex!important;
        justify-content: center!important;
        align-items: center!important;
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 700px!important;
      }
      .box {
        width: 100px!important;
        height: 100px!important;
        background: green!important;
      }`

  mywindow.document.write(`<html><head><title>${document.title}</title>`);
  mywindow.document.write(`<style>${styles}</style>`)
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write(`<h1> www.${url}</h1>`);
  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('forPrint').innerHTML);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();

  return true;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0uet49dw/12/)

Comment: It worked partially. h1 style changed but box is not shown. On JsFiddle is same problem.

Comment: it worked just enabled background graphics as @Furkan said. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable background colors and images when printing. You can do this in Chrome in the print dialog under andvanced settings.

You can also apply the `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` property to change the background print behavior.

Comment: Thank you it worked for colors. This was also helpful !